Encrypt multi PDF files with qpdf
I’m creating a batch file to encrypt multiple PDF files with qpdf. It only works if there is one PDF file even though I use “*.pdf” in the script. Please advise.
qpdf --encrypt "" PW123 256 --modify=none -- *.pdf --replace-input
